# finding tuple sublist with minimal overlap

Tags: python

**Problem :** I have a list of tuples like [ (10,20) , (20,30) , (22,24) ,  (26,30) ,  (10,28) ]  and I need to find a sublist of tuples with the minimal overlap which covers from 10,30 ( max and min are given )

I have some ideas about how to approach this problem but I was wondering if anyone can suggest any solution.

Comment: `minimal overlap which covers from 10,30` - can you please explain with your example?

Comment: as the result we are expecting [ (10,20) , (20,30) ] and not [ (10,28) ,(20,30 ) ] . All we care is having 10~30 range. I'm trying to avoid range overlapping.

Comment: I still don't understand `28-10` is `18` and that is within 10 to 30, right?

Comment: I forget to mention that consider ( 10,20 ) as a range which has 10,11,12,13 .., 20 )

Comment: You want to cover the whole range 10-30 with the subset of tuples (any number of tuples?) with the least overlap between them, yes?

Comment: 10~28 has 18 but the goal is having everything from 10~30 with less ovelap.

Comment: there is no duplicate number if we go with (10,20) , (20,30)

Comment: but if we go with ( 10,28 ) , (20,30) there will be 8 numbers exists on both range

Comment: You are looking for a greedy algorithm, and it may help to sort the list of tuples on either start of finish time first.

Comment: As it stands, this will probably get closed down as "too broad". To avoid that, spell out what your ideas are, why you are not happy with them, and ask a specific question - not just "any ideas?"

Comment: But sorting is not really going to help. As an example you might have (10,20),(11,30),(20,30) ... you dont want (10,20),(11,30) that is 9 overlap

Comment: There is not enough context. Are you allowed to have holes? Are you wanting to find the smallest number of tuples, the largest number of tuples? Do you have to use *all* of them? If the data contained a tuple (10,30) could you take that and leave the rest?

Comment: A multi-level sort, for example, might let you quickly find the set of non-overlapping tuples. Say asc(start time), desc(finish)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem :-)
Not trivial to solve. I don't see why it gets downvoted.

The following code will check all subsets, compute the continuous cover, overlap and the list of tuples that generated that cover + overlap.

Finally it gets sorted by overlap. So the first element in the output should be the one with the desired cover and the least overlap.

```
from itertools import *
import operator

def allsubsets(l):
    for s in chain( *map(lambda r: combinations(l,r), xrange(1,len(l))) ):
        yield s


# only count tuples that make consecutive ranges
def mk_cover(acc, item):
    ((curlo, curhi), tuplist, ovl) = acc
    (newlo, newhi)                 = item
    if newlo<=curhi:
        # ok, the new item possibly extends the range
        if newhi>=curhi:
            overlap = curhi - newlo
        else:
            overlap = newhi - newlo
            newhi   = curhi
        return ((curlo, newhi), tuplist+[item], ovl+overlap)
    else:
        # it doesn't so return the old accumulator
        return acc

# return a function that will inspect lists-of-tuples
# to see if they cover the range lo -> hi. If they do,
# append the covering list and the overlap to an
# accumulator; a list of solutions found so far
def mk_finder(lo, hi):
    def overlapper(acc, tuples):
        # inspect the subset of tuples, wether they 
        # cover lo -> hi 
        # sort by start value
        tuples                    = list(sorted(tuples, key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
        ((covlo, covhi), tl, ovl) = reduce(mk_cover, tuples[1:], (tuples[0], [tuples[0]], 0))
        if covlo<=lo and covhi>=hi:
            acc.append( ((covlo, covhi), tl, ovl) )
        return acc
    return overlapper
```

With the following input:

```
inp = [  (10,20) , (20,30) , (22,24) , (26,30) , (10,28) ] 

# find all that cover 10,30
found = reduce(mk_finder(10, 30), allsubsets(inp), [])

# sort by overlap
found = [(tl, ovl) for (cov, tl, ovl) in sorted(found, key=operator.itemgetter(2))
print found
```

Yields this as output (yes, there are many subsets covering the range 10-30) showing that the combination (10,20) + (20,30) covers the range 10-30 with zero overlap:

```
[([(10, 20), (20, 30)], 0),
 ([(10, 28), (26, 30)], 2),
 ([(10, 20), (20, 30), (22, 24)], 2),
 ([(10, 20), (20, 30), (26, 30)], 4),
 ([(10, 28), (22, 24), (26, 30)], 4),
 .... <snip> 
 ]
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'd still like to see the original question clarified to be sure you're answering the right one though :) For example, does [(10,20),{20,30)][(10,20),{20,30)] actually have an overlap of 1 (at 20)? That's wh I haven't upvoted the question (haven't downvoted it either)

Comment: I was thinking that on the way home. It depends on wether the range end point is inclusive or not. But that could easily be accommodated by modifying the boundary-check condition in the `overlapper`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the responses. More example relates to this problem is :

Think you have to pay a $1 for each number that you buy. and there are some sellers who are selling these ranges to you. So if you buy ( 10, 20 ) you have to pay $1 X 10 . but at the end you want to have 10 to 30 with the minimal costs. Keep in mind that you have to buy the entire range to have that number

Comment: Excellent. I'll mail you my bank details for a cut of the $1 / number :D

Comment: @haavee please do ... But I wont promise that the cost stays posivite ! Actually this is a very simplified version of a complex DNA matching problem and the input tuples is over a million pair

Comment: In that case, probably need to take a couple of efficiency measures